# when i tried to make my discord bot it gave me this error

Tags: discord, discord.js

I tried to make my discord bot but when I try to run it using node.

It says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`

I tried fiddling a little bit with brackets but it did not fix the problem, please help. If possible kindly send the whole code for me to copy-paste

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
 const prefix = ('>')
 var numeral = require('numeral');
 client.once('ready', () => {
    
  client.user.setStatus('idle');
  client.user.setActivity(' DANK HEISTS');
    console.log('Dank heists is now online');
 }); 
client.on('message' , message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot ) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (command === 'help'){
    message.channel.send('Hello, Looks like you prompted the help command. I am sorry, this bot is currently in progress so it would be appreciated for you to be patient and show your support to us !! <:3')
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(' pet')) {
    let number = message.content.replace("v pet", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v pet", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(4800000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Pepe Trophy')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/718136428219072662.gif')
    .setColor('#e1f505')
    .setDescription("Pepe Trophy is valued at" + ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
}
else if (message.content.startsWith('v pem')) {
    let number = message.content.replace("v pem", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v pem", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(8500000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Pepe Medal')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/716848179022397462.gif')
    .setColor('#e1f505')
    .setDescription("Pepe Medal is valued at" + ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
}
else if (message.content.startsWith('v pec')) {
    let number = message.content.replace("v pec", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v pec", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(1000000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Pepe Coin')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/718138332982280272.gif')
    .setColor('#e1f505')
    .setDescription("Pepe coin is valued at" + ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
}
else if (message.content.startsWith('v tide')) {
    let number = message.content.replace("v tide", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v tide", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(7000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Tidepod')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/573149030951944202.png')
    .setColor('#3121de')
    .setDescription("Tidepod is valued at" + ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
}
else if (message.content.startsWith('v chee')) {
    let number = message.content.replace("v chee", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v chee", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(5500 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Shredded Cheese')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/583318568100429826.png')
    .setColor('#b8b12e')
    .setDescription("Shredded Cheese is valued at" + ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
}
else if (message.content.startsWith('v zz')) {
    let number = message.content.replace("v zz", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v zz", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(100000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Pizza')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/693517202879414312/788070266579189790/pizza-export2.png')
    .setColor('#eb071e')
    .setDescription("Pizza is valued at" + ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
}
else if (message.content.startsWith('v mine')) {
    let number = message.content.replace("v mine", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v mine", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(2000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Landmine')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/573151813130518548.png')
    .setColor('#eb071e')
    .setDescription("Landmine is valued at" + ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
}
else {(message.content.startsWith('v jacky')) 
    let number = message.content.replace("v jacky", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v jacky", "").trim() : 1
    number = parseInt(number)
    const value = `${numeral(4500000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Jacky')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/758662115841802271.png')
    .setColor('#f0880a')
    .setDescription("Jacky O'Lanty is valued at" +   ` ${value}`)

    message.channel.send(embed)
)
}
}
;


client.login("cant reveal");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the initial `client.on('message', message => {` statement there's an open parenthesis  `(` as well as an open squiggly bracket `{`, you just accidentally shifted the position of the `)` while coding.

I've mostly just shifted the `else if` notation, since it formats nicer that way. All I had to do was pretty much scroll to the very end, delete the three rows where there's a `(`, followed by a `}`, and then another `}`, and replace it with

```
 }
});
```

(Semicolon optional)

The lesson here is that errors aren't all that scary. Sometimes it's just syntax errors, which is what happened here. Computers are always picky about it, the trick is just to remember to check it to make sure you have corresponding closed brackets to opened brackets.

Code here:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = ('>')
var numeral = require('numeral');

client.once('ready', () => {
 client.user.setStatus('idle');
 client.user.setActivity(' DANK HEISTS');
 console.log('Dank heists is now online');
}); 

client.on('message' , message => {
 if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 if (command === 'help') {
   message.channel.send('Hello, Looks like you prompted the help command. I am sorry, this bot is currently in progress so it would be appreciated for you to be patient and show your support to us !! <:3');
 } else if (message.content.startsWith(' pet')) {
   let number = message.content.replace("v pet", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v pet", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number);
   const value = `${numeral(4800000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Pepe Trophy')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/718136428219072662.gif')
   .setColor('#e1f505')
   .setDescription("Pepe Trophy is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
 } else if (message.content.startsWith('v pem')) {
   let number = message.content.replace("v pem", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v pem", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number);
   const value = `${numeral(8500000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Pepe Medal')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/716848179022397462.gif')
   .setColor('#e1f505')
   .setDescription("Pepe Medal is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
 } else if (message.content.startsWith('v pec')) {
   let number = message.content.replace("v pec", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v pec", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number)
   const value = `${numeral(1000000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Pepe Coin')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/718138332982280272.gif')
   .setColor('#e1f505')
   .setDescription("Pepe coin is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
 } else if (message.content.startsWith('v tide')) {
   let number = message.content.replace("v tide", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v tide", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number)
   const value = `${numeral(7000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Tidepod')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/573149030951944202.png')
   .setColor('#3121de')
   .setDescription("Tidepod is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
 } else if (message.content.startsWith('v chee')) {
   let number = message.content.replace("v chee", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v chee", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number)
   const value = `${numeral(5500 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Shredded Cheese')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/583318568100429826.png')
   .setColor('#b8b12e')
   .setDescription("Shredded Cheese is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
 } else if (message.content.startsWith('v zz')) {
   let number = message.content.replace("v zz", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v zz", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number)
   const value = `${numeral(100000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Pizza')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/693517202879414312/788070266579189790/pizza-export2.png')
   .setColor('#eb071e')
   .setDescription("Pizza is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
 } else if (message.content.startsWith('v mine')) {
   let number = message.content.replace("v mine", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v mine", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number)
   const value = `${numeral(2000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Landmine')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/573151813130518548.png')
   .setColor('#eb071e')
   .setDescription("Landmine is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
 } else {(message.content.startsWith('v jacky')) 
   let number = message.content.replace("v jacky", "").trim() !== "" ? message.content.replace("v jacky", "").trim() : 1
   number = parseInt(number)
   const value = `${numeral(4500000 * number).format("0,0.00")}`
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Jacky')
   .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/758662115841802271.png')
   .setColor('#f0880a')
   .setDescription("Jacky O'Lanty is valued at" + ` ${value}`);
   message.channel.send(embed);
//Here is where the order of the brackets and parenthesis was shuffled around.
 }
})

client.login("cant reveal");
```

Comment: thank you for helping me @perplexingparadox it is appreciated but it says discord is not defined in the part const client = new discord.Client();

Comment: Yeah no problem! :)

Comment: Oh, my code must've cut out. I accidentally forgot to add `const Discord = require("discord.js");` at the very top. I've edited my script so it reflects that now.